# Install a list of software via apt using a list variable

Tags: ansible, apt

While it's possible to install a list of software the following way:

```
- name: Install what I want
  apt:
    name:
      - docker
      - nmap
```

Is it also possible to use a variable that contains a list of software names instead? Like so:

```
vars:
  my_list:
    - docker
    - nmap

- name: Install what I want
  apt:
    name: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. [name](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html#parameter-name) is *"A list of package names"*. Both versions of the code are equivalent.

```yaml
vars:
  my_list:
    - docker
    - nmap
tasks:
  - name: Install what I want
    apt:
      name: "{{ my_list }}"
```

---

It's also possible to use a loop. But, this is less efficient.

```yaml
vars:
  my_list:
    - docker
    - map
tasks:
  - name: Install what I want
    apt:
      name: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ my_list }}"
```

Answer (score 2):

I last ansible version you can use next syntax:

```
vars:
  my_list: [docker, nmap]

tasks:
  - name: Install APPS
    apt:
      name: "{{ my_list }}"
      state: present
      update_cache: yes
```

Comment: This will crash with the error: `"fatal: [ ... ]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'my_list' is available"}"`. It's necessary to expand the variable `name: "{{ my_list }}"`.